# How can I send keys into a search-box element in Selenium-Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation-testing

This is the method I'm using for sending keys and it's in my parent class:

```
public void sendKeysFunction(WebElement element, String value) {
        waitUntilVisible(element);
        scrollTElement(element);
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(value); }
```

And this is the way I'm calling it:

```
dc.sendKeysFunction(dc.BrandNameInput(),"bla bla");
```

My locators are in the dialog content class and I created a new object as dc so I'm calling my element from dialog content and the methods from parent class.

It's working on usual elements but there is a search-box for bringing the options when you type 3 letters. You can manually type all of the text also. But I cannot sending keys to this element with my test automation framework. It's clicking the element but not sending letters. I tried to use different solutions like Keys.ENTER but it didn't worked. I am sure of my locator. What should I do?

I am expecting to be able to send keys to my elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check or change the element tag with which you try to interact. It is possible you have to interact with the ancestor or descender of the current element, or any other. It will be better if you provide, at least, schematically the structure of your element with the closest elements and tags. At least it isn't clear with which element you try to interact - not all HTML elements might be modified with `sendKeys` method.

Generally, there are several ways to set text into a web element (`input`), except `sendKeys()` calling.

1. JavascriptExecutor using:

```java
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", element, "YOUR TEXT");
```

2. For example, if `input` tag has the `value` attribute you can try to set the value of this attribute:

```java
WebElement element = ...
String script = "arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);";
jsExecutor.executeScript(script, element, "value", "YOUR TEXT");
```

3. Using Action library:

```java
Actions actions = new Actions(getDriver());
actions.sendKeys(element, "YOUR TEXT").perform();
```

Comment: 3. suggestion worked well. I defined action class wrong. Thank you so much.  I have another issue. I would be appreciated if you can answer. As you can see in my code block above, I implement the scroll down into the send keys method. But It's now scrolling to the element. How can I do this in different ways? Thank you so much from now.

Comment: @HasanEbrarAlarçin Sorry, but I am not sure I understand correctly. If you don't need scrolling just delete the method `scrollTElement(element);`. Or create a new one that doesn't make scrolling. In general, this method violates the SRP and has too many responsibilities. At least the `scrollTElement(element);` should be deleted and called in the cases where this feature is needed.

Comment: If the answer helped solve the issue, please mark it as the right answer.